# Cosmos DB: Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 1001; Reason: ();

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using [Cosmos DB repository](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IEvangelist.Azure.CosmosRepository) and trying to add new item for below object.

```
[Container(nameof(Notifications))]
    [PartitionKeyPath("/UserUUId")]
    public class Notifications : Item
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RequestID", Order = 2)]
        public string RequestID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NotificationType", Order = 3)]
        public int NotificationType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SubType", Order = 4)]
        public string SubType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserUUId", Order = 5)]
        public string UserUUId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Payer", Order = 6)]
        public string Payer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PayerName", Order = 7)]
        public string PayerName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Account", Order = 8)]
        public string Account { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AccountName", Order = 9)]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Created", Order = 10)]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Updated", Order = 11)]
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Status", Order = 12)]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MetaData", Order = 13)]
        public Dictionary<string, string> MetaData { get; set; }

        protected override string GetPartitionKeyValue() => UserUUId;
    }
```

This is my code code to add new item:

```
public class UINotificationPublisher : IUINotificationPublisher
{

   private readonly IRepository<Notifications> _uiNotificationsRepository;

    public UINotificationPublisher(
        IRepositoryFactory factory
    
        )
    {
        _uiNotificationsRepository = factory.RepositoryOf<Notifications>();

    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(IEnumerable<UserSubscriptions> userSubscriptions, CardGroupEvent @event, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            var uiSubscriptions = userSubscriptions
                .Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.EventType == (int)EventType.CARD_GROUP_CHANGED && y.Channels.Contains((int)ChannelType.UI)));

            if (uiSubscriptions.Any())
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"UI notification subscriptions found, requestID:{@event.RequestID}");

                List<Notifications> uiNotifications = new List<Notifications>();

                foreach (var item in uiSubscriptions)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"creating UI notification for UUID:{item.UUID}. requestID:{@event.RequestID}");

                    uiNotifications.Add(CreateItemAsync(item, @event));

                    logger.LogInformation($"successfully created UI Notification for UUID:{item.UUID}: {@event.RequestID}");
                }
                await _uiNotificationsRepository.CreateAsync(uiNotifications);
            }
            else
                logger.LogInformation($"No UI notification subscriptions found: requestID:{@event.RequestID}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private Notifications CreateItemAsync(UserSubscriptions userSubscription, CardGroupEvent @event)
    {
        Notifications notifications = new Notifications
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
            RequestID = @event.RequestID,
            NotificationType = (int)EventType.CARD_GROUP_CHANGED,
            SubType = @event.EventSubType,
            UserUUId = userSubscription.UUID,
            Payer = @event.PayerNumber,
            PayerName = @event.PayerName,
            Account = @event.AccountNumber,
            AccountName = @event.AccountName,
            MetaData = GetMetaData(@event),
            Status = (int)NotificationStatus.UnRead

        };
      
        return notifications;
        
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetMetaData(CardGroupEvent @event)
    {
       

        var metaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     
        metaData.Add(nameof(@event.AccountNumber), @event.AccountNumber);
        metaData.Add(nameof(@event.AccountName), @event.AccountName);
      
        return metaData;
    }
}
```

Cosmos DB Respository CreateAsync:

[image]

I am getting below exception while inserting new item:

> "Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400);
> Substatus: 1001; ActivityId: 68af0c72-ff2d-4055-8898-b94a08f18ead;
> Reason: ();"

Below is the stack trace:

> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage
> responseMessage, Func2 createResponse) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateItemResponse[T](ResponseMessage
> responseMessage) at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.d__541.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.d__391.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.d__301.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository.DefaultRepository1.d__7.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at
> CardGroupEventSubscriber.Publishers.UINotificationPublisher.d__2.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\notification-subscribers\dev\Notification-Microservices\CardGroupEventSubscriber\CardGroupEventSubscriber\Publishers\UINotificationPublisher.cs:line
> 49

Comment: The partition key must match a property in the document body. Try changing partition key for the container and fix your deletion code. Make sure you correctly specify the partition key.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the [Troubleshooting doc for Bad Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-bad-request#wrong-partition-key-value)

> A response with this error means you are executing an operation and passing a partition key value that does not match the document's body value for the expected property. If the collection's partition key path is /myPartitionKey, the document has a property called myPartitionKey with a value that does not match what was provided as partition key value when calling the SDK method.

You are not sharing the code that calls the Cosmos DB SDK (just calls to some repository object) so it's hard to point to the right code, but if you are calling for example:

```
container.CreateItem(<item>, new PartititionKey(pkValue))
```

This error would mean the `new PartitionKey(pkValue)` you are passing is incorrect, it is not the value of the container's Partition Key Definition property in the `item`.

The code might be assuming the Partition Key Definition is on (for example `/Payer`) but the Container's actual Partition Key Definition is another (for example `\id`).

Comment: The cosmos DB respository library which I am using, it is not accepting the Partition key as a parameter, It is accepting only the object.

Comment: When you go to the library you mention's github repository (https://github.com/IEvangelist/azure-cosmos-dotnet-repository) you see they do mention the Partition Key. Your model is even defining it: `protected override string GetPartitionKeyValue() => UserUUId;` Your model is saying that the UserUUId is the partition key, make sure your Container has a Partition Key Definition of `/UserUUId`

Comment: Yes! I have cross verified, Notifications container has a Partition key definition of /UserUUId.

Comment: Then I would reach to the library's author, the error code is clear on which scenario it happens. Some code (either yours or the library's) is passing the wrong Partition Key value for that operation.

Comment: I observed one scenario, when we're trying PartitionKeyPath name with camel case, then create new item working fine, But when we're giving PartitionKeyPath name in pascal case then create new item giving this error. So is this library only supporting PartitionKeyPath name only in camel case?

Comment: PartitionKeyPaths are case sensitive. If the path is `/myProperty` then the property in the document should be `myProperty`. If you are changing the casing, that is the root cause of your problem. For questions about the specific library, please reach to the library author through their repository, I am not the author, so cannot comment.

Comment: Thanks! @Matias, I have opend an ticket in the github for this issue https://github.com/IEvangelist/azure-cosmos-dotnet-repository/issues/274